# How to stop a Daemon thread in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, python-multithreading

I want to kill or stop this thread, I am not sure how to do it safely, I know the daemon thread will be killed when the program stops, but I want to kill or stop the thread.

```
def a():
   def b():
     os.system()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=b, daemon=True)
return t1
```

```
class A:
   def test():
      t1 = a()
      t1.start()

      """I want to stop this thread here."""
```

Comment: you could make it check for a value in a certain variable once in a while and if the values matches to the termination values it will break from a loop and finish executing it's code, p.s. (let me know if you find a better way, I'd like to know also if there's a better way of doing it)

Comment: It is a bad idea to cancel threads, is it not in standard `Thread` API, though there is internal method to to it, but it can lead to unpredictable results in other threads. To stop any `Thread` - use `threading.Event` to stop thread from another `Thread`. If you want cancel/kill threads. consider using child processes instead.